# Sieves theorem no numbers in array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sieve-of-eratosthenes

My justPrimes array doesn't appear to be working and I cant figure out why, when I printed it out on the console to see what was in it I just got a bunch of random characters repeated over and over.. Could anyone spot the issue?

```
    int[] numberArray = new int[N];

    int primes = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i < numberArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(numberArray[i] == 0)
        {
            primes++;
            int multiple = 2*i;
            while(multiple < N)
            {
                numberArray[multiple] = 1;
                multiple = multiple + i;
            }
        }
    }


    int[] justPrimes = new int[primes];
    for(int c = 2; c < numberArray.length; c++)
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < primes; index++)
        {
            if(numberArray[c] == 0)
            {
                justPrimes[index] = c;
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Can you post the random characters it did output?

Comment: "when I printed it out on the console" but how exactly did you print them? Was it perhaps something like `System.out.println(yourArray);`?

Comment: To add new informations in your question use [edit] option placed below your post.

Answer (score 0):

Your second part when you try to fill in `justPrimes` is wrong:

```
    for(int index = 0; index < primes; index++)
    {
        if(numberArray[c] == 0)
        {
            justPrimes[index] = c;
        }
    }
```

This will fill in whole array `justPrimes` with just one value `c`, so `justPrimes` will only contain the last prime number <= N.

You need to `break` after filling in the `justPrimes`, and the second `if` condition is not enough.

To fix:

```
    for(int c = 2; c < numberArray.length; c++)
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < primes; index++)
        {
               if(numberArray[c] == 0 && justPrimes[index] == 0)//Need to find the correct index, which has not been filled in yet.
               {
                  justPrimes[index] = c;
                  break; //You forgot this
               }
        }
    }
```

Better solution:

```
    for(int c = 2; c < numberArray.length; c++)
    {
        if(numberArray[c] == 0)
        {
            for(int index = 0; index < primes; index++)
            {
               if(justPrimes[index] == 0)
               {
                  justPrimes[index] = c;
                  break; //You forgot this
               }
            }
        }

    }
```

Even better:

```
    int index = 0;
    for(int c = 2; c < numberArray.length; c++)
    {
        if(numberArray[c] == 0)
        {
            justPrimes[index++] = c;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This extra loop is breaking your logic (trying to write each prime to multiple slots):

```
        for(int index = 0; index < primes; index++)
```

Seems like you really wanted to:

```
    int index = 0; // instead of looping on index, initialize it to zero here
    for (int c = 2; c < numberArray.length; c++) {
        if (numberArray[c] == 0) {
            justPrimes[index] = c;
            index++; // then increment index here so next prime goes in next slot
        }
    }
```